# InstalledFileLocator on a NetBeans Maven platform project

Tags: maven, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to figure out where/how do I create the equivalent of the release folder on ANT project so my Maven application can find files in it using InstalledFileLocator.

I found http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven/nbm-maven-plugin/nbm-mojo.html#nbmResources but I can't make it work. I tried in the application, a module, etc without luck.

Any hints?

**Edit:**
Code can be found [here](https://javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-rcp) in the Marauroa-Server-Manager folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it was done:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                ...
                <nbmResources>                     
                    <nbmResource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.gif</include>
                        </includes>
                    </nbmResource>
                </nbmResources> 
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In my case, I was missing the nbmResources tags surrounding the nbmResource element.

Comment: I forgot the nbmRessources tag too!  The link to the related doc: https://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/nbm-mojo.html#nbmResources